# Flash Builder not showing desktop Application

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

While learning Flash Builder, I am testing a simple application that runs in a browser, the code is like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
private function doSomething():void
{
myPanel.visible = false;
}
]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Panel id="myPanel" x="32" y="38" width="445" height="316" title="My Panel">
<s:Label x="206" y="34" text="Label"/>
<s:HSlider x="171" y="121"/>
<s:Button click="doSomething()" x="182" y="198" label="Goodbye"/>
</s:Panel>
</s:Application>
```

When I run the application in a browser if show fine, but when I set the a project up with the settings for Desktop Application I can't getting anything to show up. I have no problems listed in the problems view. Does anybody have some advice on why I don't see a compiled application.Thanks

Comment: firstofall how you set web application to run in desktop application.

Answer (score 3):

First thing convert your Flex web project to desktop application with flash builder like this :

[image]

then change the tag `<s:Application />` with `<s:WindowedApplication />`
(Flash builder suggest by default to change this tag when changing project type)

your finally project look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication  xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"  
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">


    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            private function doSomething():void
            {
                myPanel.visible = false;
            }

        ]]>

    </fx:Script>
    <s:Panel id="myPanel" x="32" y="38" width="445" height="316" title="My Panel">
        <s:Label x="206" y="34" text="Label"/>
        <s:HSlider x="171" y="121"/>
        <s:Button click="doSomething()" x="182" y="198" label="Goodbye"/>
    </s:Panel>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [Spark WindowedApplication](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/WindowedApplication.html) for Desktop Applications.  `s:Application` is only for web.